# CMSTestCase results in 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-cms

I'm trying to write some simple tests with FactoryBoy to test an app on a Django CMS site. I'm using Django 1.7.8 and django-cms 3.0.13 with factory-boy 2.5.2

I setup the test initially using `unitest.TestCase` then changed to `CMSTestCase` and under the CMS test case it just returns `AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'`

Are different database settings required when running `CMSTestCase`? There's nothing unusual about my test;

```
from cms.test_utils.testcases import CMSTestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import Client
from django.test.utils import override_settings

from ...factories import EventFactory, EntrantFactory


class MaxEntrantTest(CMSTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.event = EventFactory.create()
        self.entrants = EntrantFactory.create_batch(self.event.number_of_places)

        # Every test needs a client.
        self.client = Client()

    @override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='online_entry.tests.test_urls')
    def test_details(self):
        # Issue a GET request.
        response = self.client.get(reverse('online_entry:entry'))

        # Check that the response is 404 event full.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

Comment: Was this test working at all when it was a `unittest.TestCase`? Note that `CMSTestCase` is rarely needed.

Comment: @Louis Not quite, I was getting an error about not using SekizaiContext to render the page, but considered that to be running just an error then within the test itself.